# Resize bottom border on a heading element to fit the text width and also be responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border, centering

I want to make the bottom border narrower and responsive while keeping text centered at the same time. How could I achieve that? I tried using width property explicitly but that is apparently not working.

DEMO: https://www.bootply.com/jEB0e4Ao61

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container text-center features">
  <h1>Features</h1><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1. use `display:inline-block`;
2. set `width: auto`

**Change from a block element so the border will resize to the width of the text:**

`<h1>` is a `block` element, which will automatically stretch to 100% width of the container. setting width to auto or a percentage will apply to the default width, i.e. 50% will be 50% of the container width.

Using `inline-block` and width of `auto` will make the heading only as wide as the heading itself, which means you won't need media queries for different screen sizes. This will make the border the exact width of the heading itself.

**To make the "underline" extend wider than the text width:**

If you would like extra space at the sides of the heading, you can use padding to do this. For example:

```
padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;
```

will add 20px to either side of the heading, extending the element width which will also extend the bottom border by 20px on both sides.

**Working demo:**

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 20px 5px; /* this adds 20px to the sides, extending the border  */
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container text-center features">
  <h1>Features</h1><br>
</div>
<p>The "underline" for this heading extends 20px either side of the text by setting the left and width padding to 20px</p>
```

Comment: This is a bad/hacky solution because it requires adding a `<br>` after each heading.

Comment: @Inigo Actually no, this doesn't require a `<br>` to be added after each heading... if you try it, you will see that the `<br>` isn't necessary at all for this to work, the only reason it is included is because it was in the OP's original code.

Comment: I should clarify, it requires either a `<br>` or a wrapping `<span>` or some other wrapper to make the inline-block header behave as a normal block. I consider it a hack because one has to change the HTML structure to achieve this, rather than a pure CSS solution to "resize bottom border on a heading element to fit the text width".

Comment: @Inigo This actually is a pure CSS solution to the question that was asked because the original HTML already had the `<h1>` contained in a separate element. And it isn't unusual to have a `<hx>` element in a separate container like this... some CMSs generate HTML with the headings inside a container element, so it's not an uncommon question or code structure. :)