# css underline text only with arrow centered

Tags: css, text, underline

i'm trying to underline my text with an additional arrow centered on the ligne.
when doing this i can't center my text in the page.

```css
.souligne {
  line-height: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00a7a8;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.souligne:before {
  content: '\25bc';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 5em;
  color: #00a7a8;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="souligne" style="text-align:center;">THIS IS MY HEADER</h2>
```

The text is not centered when doing this.

---

```css
.souligne {
  line-height: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00a7a8;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.souligne:before {
  content: '\25bc';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 5em;
  color: #00a7a8;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="souligne" style="text-align:center">THIS IS MY HEADER</h2>

<br>

<center><h2 class="souligne">THIS IS MY HEADER</h2></center>
```

so when using `style="text-align:center"` in H2 it doesn't center the text, it works only when using `<center>`.

Comment: Found a suitable solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963746/resize-bottom-border-on-a-heading-element-to-fit-the-text-width-and-also-be-resp

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Thanks @Evgeny Veliky this is very close to what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks i give a look

Answer (score 0):

You can set h2 to inline-block, and change position of before pseudo-element to 50% se negative margin to half of the arrow and it will be always center fit with title length

```css
h2 {
line-height: 17px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-bottom: 2px solid #00a7a8;
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
}
h2:before {
    content: '\25bc';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-12px;
    color: #00a7a8;
}
```

```html
<h2>The Header Is Here</h2>
```

Comment: check my code and try to reproduce on jsfiddle, all you have to do is to set display:inline-block;  on h2 and at h2:before change position left to 50% and add margin-left:-12px;

Comment: it doesn't work look, btw i'm doing a class, i don't want to modify h2 only. http://jsfiddle.net/0dqmjpch/1/

Comment: actualy i don't understand why the text is not centered when using : style="text-align: center;" in H2, example here : http://jsfiddle.net/aw9quod2/ it works only with <center> tag

Comment: .souligne {
  line-height: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00a7a8;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.souligne:before {
  content: '\25bc';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 5em;
  color: #00a7a8;
}

Comment: Thanks @Renato Hoxha this is working. But once again i can't add a text-align tag in H2 in order to choose if i want to center it or push the text to left or right. Anyway as i wanted to center my text, this is the correct answer for me. You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK so based on the @Renato Hoxha help, this is what finaly worked for my project.

```css
.souligne {
 color: #ea942f;
 line-height: 17px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ea942f;
 position: relative;
 display: table;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.souligne:before {
 content: '\25bc';
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 color: #ea942f;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="souligne">THIS IS MY HEADER</h2>
```